# Do iOS Apps require a registration flow?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have a website that hosts online courses for registered users.

I am now creating an app that will:

1. Ask users to login,
2. Allow the user to navigate their courses,
3. Allow the user to play course content.

My question is, will Apple accept an app that:

1. Requires a user to login before gaining any value?
2. Does not allow users to register on the App (you have to register on
   the website, there is a link on the app login page to the website
   registration - the registration is free).

The Apple guidelines do not explicitly say that you have to be able to register on the app. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: don't know about the requirement no. 2 :)

Comment: Yes - this is my main concern.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question, it's an App Store requirement question.

Comment: The better questions is "is there any benefit to providing an app over visiting the website?".

Comment: *Does not allow users to register on the App (you have to register on the website, there is a link on the app login page to the website registration - the registration is free).*, why not present the website in the application for signup, [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/index.html)?

Comment: The website is too large / cumbersome and it's not responsively designed. It would not be a pleasant experience. The registration is complex as it involved book codes / class activations / school setups etc.

Comment: @Almo Requirements / Programming are so intertwined that I believe the question relevant.

Comment: @rmaddy We need to use an app to leverage device hardware that is not accessible to websites on mobile browsers (eg video / audio recording).

Comment: App Store Requirement questions should go here: http://apple.stackexchange.com In this case, the question has nothing to do with programming. there's no question about how to code this, it's about interface design to pass the app store checks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my experience Apple will allow, I have 3 apps in App Store that have similar workflow you mentioned.

My App Works like:

1. When app is opened it ask for a PIN
2. User can get the PIN by registering to our web-site
3. After entering the PIN my app allow the user to continue

Comment: I have apps that only let you access through a code. I have seen apps rejected because they asked for mandatory registration, arguing that the app didn't let the user know about the contents before having to register. I would say there is a risk they may reject your app.